# How to add a Rewrite Rule / Category Structure

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I'm currently trying to use `add_rewrite_rule()` to create a rewrite (duh!), for a custom taxonomy page.

I've added the rewrite tag "sort" with the following code:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%sort%','([^&]+)');
```

The issue is I'm not very familiar with the rewrite structure and I'm struggling.. I have a rewrite rule that is getting close, but still not quite working.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^vehicle-make/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=40&sort=$matches[1]','top');
```

The problem is it's pulling in the wrong page; I'm needing to show the taxonomy archive for the specific term. So instead of a page ID I'm guessing I just need to pull in the taxonomy name and current term archive.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct url and patched the rewrite and it works perfectly now! This is what I ended with!

```
add_rewrite_rule('^vehicle-make/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?vehicle-make=$matches[1]&sort=$matches[2]','top');
```